# Extract elements from a list and set it to variable (set_fact)

Tags: list, loops, ansible

I am passing the following list to my script as an extra var

```
ansible-playbook /home/ec2-user/ansible/start.yml --extra-vars  multi_config=['aa|111','bb|222','cc|444']
```

This is the only way I found to pass variables that contain a list or key/values (with the `|` separator)  and I can't use json file as argument...

I'd like to loop this `multi_config` list and search for the element that contains "bb" and set it to a variable with `set_fact` to use it later.

I can load the list like this:

```yaml
- name: set multi_config
  set_fact:
    multi_config: "{{ multi_config}}"
  when: multi_config is defined
```

But how can I extract the element that contains "bb"?

Answer (score 1):

The extra variables passed to Ansible from the command line are always strings, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ multi_config|type_debug }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: str
```

Use the filter *from_yaml* and convert the string to the list and iterate the items. There are many options for how to parse the data. For example, split the keys and values, and combine a dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        mc_dict: "{{ mc_dict|default({})|combine({_key: _val}) }}"
      loop: "{{ multi_config|from_yaml }}"
      vars:
        _key: "{{ item.split('|').0 }}"
        _val: "{{ item.split('|').1 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  mc_dict:
    aa: '111'
    bb: '222'
    cc: '444'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a much better way to pass your info as `--extra-vars` supports [inlined json](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#json-string-format)

```
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ multi_config | type_debug }}" \
    -e '{"multi_config":{"aa":111,"bb":222,"cc":444}}'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "dict"
}

$ ansible localhost -m debug -a var=multi_config \
    -e '{"multi_config":{"aa":111,"bb":222,"cc":444}}'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "multi_config": {
        "aa": 111,
        "bb": 222,
        "cc": 444
    }
}

$ ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ multi_config.cc }}" \
    -e '{"multi_config":{"aa":111,"bb":222,"cc":444}}'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "444"
}
```

Comment: can i pass inline json and ordenary key=val parameters ? ( as there allready key=value parameters used in with the playbook

Comment: You can pass everything in the same json, or ppass several extra vsrrs options in the same command line, mixing json and "classic" syntax. The best way to figure it out is too try it.